# AWS SSH: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, server

I'm trying to connect to AWS instance. I know that I definitely have the keypair downloaded on my desktop, but for some reason it doesn't recognize it? I've changed the permissions by using `chmod 400` but the following still happens:

`martycep:~ martincepeda1$ ssh -v -i “privatekey.pem” ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Warning: Identity file privatekey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/martincepeda1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
martycep:~ martincepeda1$`

Any suggestions/ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: " Identity file privatekey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory" are you sure .pem file is in same directory?

Comment: @Nambari I was in the wrong directory. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have correct access rights to your public key.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Identity file privatekey.pem not accessible: **No such file or
>   directory**

This output says that you don't have any file called "privatekey.pem"

Maybe you changed the key permissions like:

```
chmod 0400 **~/.ssh/privatekey.pem**
```

And the file should look like this:

```
-r--------+ 1 user group     1671 Jun  5 11:37 privatekey.pem
```

In that scenario you should do:

```
ssh -i **~/.ssh/privatekey.pem** ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Check where is your key!

After solving that, don't forget you had to add the public key in the host: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

```
cat 'your_public_key' >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Otherwise your privatekey won't match with the public one in the server.

Comment: Yeah I had to `cd` to where my file was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

- You are using the correct key location.
- The Key has correct permissions.
- Are you using the correct Key?

Comment: I was in the wrong directory. Thanks.